# How to parse online JSON url and display it on android's listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

Hi I'm currently developing an android application that requires to parse JSON from web and display the name, thumbnail to listview.

**here's the JSON looks like from http://example.com/api **

```
{
  id: 4
  name: "Person A"
  thumb: "http://www.juice.ph/article_images/0015/5108/movie_poster_DIVERGENT_214x315-50.jpg"
}
{
  id: 5
  name: "Person B"
  thumb: "http://www.juice.ph/article_images/0015/5108/movie_poster_DIVERGENT_214x315-50.jpg"
}
```

What is the easiest and good approach on displaying the sample JSON to the listview including the thumb? I know that this will be using custom listview adapter but some tutorials online are too complicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download the content in url as string.

Creare a model class same as json structure and parse the JSON using GSON. You will get a List as response as your json is array.

Now create a custom ArrayAdapter and override getview() , add the response list to the adapter.